# "1-year term contract" vs. "1-year contract"

Tags: synonyms

What's the difference, if any, between "1-year term contract" and "1-year contract"? I.e., what does the "term" add?

[Example of use](https://www.xfinity.com/digital/offers/plan-builder):

[image]

Comment: I think you would be better advised to ask this question on the Law site - specifying the name of the particular legal jurisdiction in question.  Legal terminaology and commercial jargon can vary from place to place.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These two constructions are often used interchangeably but may have different legal meanings according to the local laws.

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example of difference in legal meaning for "1-year term contract" vs. "1-year contract"?

Comment: I do not but i can assure you some exist. Law bores me stiff. Recommended action is web search using the term "legal definition of term contract".

Comment: @Downvoters: Why the downvotes?